# How to zoom in and out webpage in Firefox using Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

Try to use javascript to zoom in and zoom out webpage on Firefox but nothing happen.

```
Execute javascript  document.body.style.zoom="70%"
```

Please anyone have any idea to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use those script on firefox. Just try below script:

```
Execute javascript       document.body.style.MozTransform = "scale(0.7)"
```

> Scale = 1, It's mean 100%.